# How to make buttons responsive in SLDS?

Tags: slds

I have some table written in Salesforce Lightning Design System.
There are two buttons in leftmost column of each row, and I want to make these buttons smaller in mobile media.

Fragment of HTML.

---

```
<table class="slds-table slds-table_bordered slds-max-medium-table_stacked-horizontal slds-table_col-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr class="slds-text-title_caps">
            <th scope="col">
                <div title="Action">Action</div>                
            </th>
        </tr>
        ...
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
       <td class="slds-text-align_right">
          <div>
              <button type="button" class="slds-button slds-button_brand">Save</button>
              <button type="button" class="slds-button slds-button_neutral">Auto Check</button>
          </div>
       </td>
    </tr>
    ...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Responsive Does not mean that your elements will become smaller. A web responsive design basically means that your DOM will adapt/re-arange itself according to screensize/device that is being used (amongst other things)

Normally, SLDS is Responsive OOTB, what you are trying to achieve is a custom functionality.

You should be able to easily achieve this with Media queries and CSS.

For Example, using slds-size_x-of-x on your button accoridng to device/zcreensize will change the size of the button.

you can also explicitly specify a size using [CSS units of measuring](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)